# Can't find my.cnf file so I can enable InnoDB - is there another way?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to Magento running on a share server, and am having difficulty.

When I look at the engines in PHPmyAdmin, I get `InnoDB DISABLED`. So I look in /etc/, and there is no my.cnf file.

There is a ftpquota and a .boxtrapper file, but nothing else.

I know I can probably create a new one, but this is a server that hosts a lot of sites. I'm afraid I will mess someone up.

So is there a way to maybe create a my.cnf file that only enable InnoDB and doesn't effect anything else? Or is there another way to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Check ps -ef to see where the location of mySQL is - on some servers, it may also show the location of the configuration file, which may (or may not) be writable for you.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no my.cnf file, it's possible to create one and upon restart MySQL will use it.

However, you said it's a shared server?  I'm afraid that your hosting provider has chosen to disable it because they want to be cheap (and save memory).

See my related answer here:
[Is INNODB enabled by default in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137668/is-innodb-enabled-by-default-in-mysql/1350540#1350540)

It's (very) unlikely you will have permissions to override what your hosting provider has done.